# How to recognize those media links to set proper player?

Tags: php, media-player, media

I've real complex idea, Okay anyway let say we have the following links

```
    www.some_site.com/test.wmv                   // media player
    www.some_site.com/test.mp4                  // jwplayer
    www.some_site.com/test.flv                 // jwplayer
    www.some_site.com/test.rmvb               // real player
    www.some_site.com/test.mov               // quick time
    www.youtube.com/watch?v=cyvX3_3nqfc     // jwplayer
```

Looks like media links so as far as I know there is no player that support all extensions hence I'm going to use for each of those links its player based on its extension.

**Example 1** (for `wmv` will embedded Windows media player code)

```
  <object type="video/x-ms-wmv"
  data="test.wmv"
  width="400" height="350">
  <param name="src" value="test.wmv" />
  <param name="autostart" value="true" />
  <param name="controller" value="true" />
  </object>
```

**Example 2** (for `mov` will embedded quick time code)

```
    <object classid="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B"
    codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab"
    width="400" height="350">
    <param name="src" value="test.mov" />
    <param name="controller" value="true" />
    <param name="autoplay" value="true" />
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    <object type="video/quicktime"
      data="test.mov"
      width="400" height="350">
    <param name="autoplay" value="true" />
    <param name="controller" value="true" />
```

Okay you must have got my point so the question is how using PHP can get the extension of each file of the link in order call its proper player

```
if ($ext === 'wmv' || $ext === 'asf') {

echo "media player";

} else if($ext === 'mov') {

echo "qick time";


} else if($ext === 'rmvb') {

echo "real player";

} else if($ext === 'youtube' || $ext === 'flv' || $ext === 'mp4') {

echo "jwplayer is good";

} else {

echo "die well";

}
```

**What For**

In fact I'm trying write class that can identify the link then call its proper player embedded code to my webpage and will to support as many as I can of different media extensions so this is basic example that would really helps me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach, it should be flexible enough.

```
<?php
class VideoRenderer {
    protected
        $engines = array();

    public function register(VideoRendererEngine $engine) {
        array_push($this->engines, $engine);
        return $this;
    }

    public function render($video) {
        foreach ($this->engines as $engine) {
            if ($engine->accepts($video)) {
                return $engine->render($video);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}

interface VideoRendererEngine {
    /**
     * @return bool Whether this Engine can render the video supplied
     */
    public function accepts($video);
    /**
     * @return string Rendered HTML
     */
    public function render($video);
}

class WmvVideoEngine implements VideoRendererEngine {
    public function accepts($video) {
        return 'wmv' === substr($video, -3, 3);
    }

    public function render($video) {
        return '<object type="video/x-ms-wmv"
            data="' . $video . '"
            width="400" height="350">
            <param name="src" value="test.wmv" />
            <param name="autostart" value="true" />
            <param name="controller" value="true" />
        </object>';
    }
}

class AsfVideoEngine implements VideoRendererEngine {
    public function accepts($video) {
        return 'wmv' === substr($video, -3, 3);
    }

    public function render($video) {
        return '<object type="video/x-ms-wmv"
            data="' . $video . '"
            width="400" height="350">
            <param name="src" value="test.wmv" />
            <param name="autostart" value="true" />
            <param name="controller" value="true" />
        </object>';
    }
}

$renderer = new VideoRenderer;
$renderer->register(new WmvVideoEngine);
$renderer->register(new AsfVideoEngine);
echo $renderer->render('http://www.example.com/test.wmv');
```